# Two level pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Say we have the following array:

```
char *names[]={"Abc", "Def", "Ghi", "Klm", "Nop"};
```

If we want to create a pointer that points to the array above, why should we use a two-level pointer as follows?

```
char **p1 = names;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't created a "pointer that points to the array above". You have instead ended up creating a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Off topic, you asked a lot of question in SO, but a poor rate of accepting answers (bellow 50%). why?

Comment: `p1` is not pointer to array ,It just point to its first pointer in array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `names` is an array `[]`, of `char *`, i.e., an array of pointers to `char`.

Meanwhile `p1` is a pointer which points to a pointer to `char`, i.e., a pointer to `char *`. You can assign `names` to it because the array decays to a pointer to its first element, and the first element of `names` is a pointer to `char`, hence `names` decays to a pointer to `char *`. This is the same type – `char **` – as `p1`, therefore they are compatible.

(On another note, the element type of `names` is incorrect; the string literals are constant, and thus it should be `const char *names[]`, and similarly `p1` should be `const char**` – pointer to pointer to `const char`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can see it this way, when you need to point to an integer array, you need to use a **pointer to int**.

```
int arr[];
int* a;

a = arr;
```

So, in this context, you need a pointer to the elements in the array `names[]`. What are the elements in that array. Its `char*`. So you would need a **pointer to `char*`**. Which translates to **pointer to pointer to char**.
That is

```
char *names[]={"Abc", "Def", "Ghi", "Klm", "Nop"};

char **p1 = names;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a pointer that points to array

```
char *names[]={"Abc", "Def", "Ghi", "Klm", "Nop"};
```

then you have to write

```
char * ( *p1 )[sizeof( names ) / sizeof( *names )] = &names;
```

If you want to create a pointer that points to the elements of the array then you indeed should write

```
char **p1 = names;
```

In this case pointer `p1` is initialized by the address of the address of the first character of string literal `"Abc"`.

So for example expression `*p1` will contain the value of the first element of array `names` that in turn (the value) is the address of the first character of string literal `"Abc"` and has type `char *`.

If you will apply dereferencing the second time `**p1` you will get the first character of the string literal itslef that is `'A'`.

For example

```
printf( "%c\n", **p1 );
```

To make it more clear let's consider a general situation.
If you have an array with elements of type `T` like this

```
T a[N];
```

then this array in expressions is converted to pointer to its first element that will have type `T *`. So if you want to declare such a pointer yourself you should write

```
T *p1 = a;
```

This record is equivalent to

```
T *p1 = &a[0];
```

In your original example type `T` corresponds to type `char *` - the type of the elements ofarray names. So after substitution `char *` for `T` you will get

```
char * *p1 = names;
^^^^^^
  T
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not create a pointer to array of pointers .It actually is pointer to first pointer of array.

If you want to create a pointer to array of pointers write something like  this -

```
char *names[MAX];
char* (*p1)[MAX] = &names;
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: Thanks to the comment, the array is actually bound here: because the compiler can deduce its size from the initializers.

---

From its declaration, `names` is: an array of pointers to `char`. A bound array **decays** to a pointer to its first element. Elements of `names` being pointer to char, when used in an expression `names` is implicitly converted to a pointer to a pointer to char.

This is why you can assign `names` in your second line:

```
char **p1 = names;
```

So `p1` points to the first element in `names`, which for most practical purposes is *like* pointing to the array (in memory, an array being juxtaposed objects). Technically, you are pointing to the first element though.

Comment: Why the downvotes ? Is it not answering the question while trying to be technically accurate (introducing the nuance between bound and unbound).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps because the array isn't unbounded, its size is calculated and bound at compile time.

Comment: @names Thank you for taking the time !

Comment: @Arkku Thank you, I totally missed that !